# I get 0 instead of empty string in polymer's paper-dropdown-menu (core-menu)

Tags: data-binding, types, polymer, web-component

I am using a dynamic dropdown menu with the options being fed in with databinding. The data looks like this:

```
options = [
 { 
    name: "Alle",
    value: ""
 },
    name: "100",
    value: "100"
 },
 // ...
]
```

And the code like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Select">
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
    <core-menu class="menu" valueattr="data-value" selected="{{search.selectedItem}}">
      <template repeat="{{item in options}}">
        <paper-item data-value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

However when selecting the first item the `search.selectedItem` gets populated with the value 0 and upon inspection it seems the core-menu's `selected` attribute is also the integer 0.

All the other values work as expected (strings).

When I look in Chrome inspect element the rendered html looks like this:

```
<paper-item data-value="" tabindex="0" class="core-selected" active="">Alle</paper-item>
```

How can I force it to be an empty string, just like my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the code of [`core-selector`](https://github.com/Polymer/core-selector/blob/master/core-selector.html) highly relies on checks like:

```
SMTH = this.selectedItem ? TRUTHY, FALSEY;
```

Empty string is being evaluated to `FALSEY`, unlike arbitrary non-empty string. That’s why the controller goes crazy on empty strings.

I would suggest you to use the following workaround. Let’s define a filter for your `selectedItem`:

```
<core-menu class="menu" 
           valueattr="data-value" 
           selected="{{selectedItem | fixZero}}">
<!--                                ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑     -->
```

It should be [`both-way-bound`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#custom-filters):

```
  fixZero: {
    toDOM: function(value) { // called when model changes
      return value;
    },
    toModel: function(value) { // called when DOM changes
      return value === 0 ? '' : value;
    }
  }
```

That would cheat the `core-selector` and reset the value back to empty string *after* all verifications were done (assuming you have no zero values on purpose.)

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/L5fNgevDERNo7tJQyU0n?p=preview

Comment: I'm guessing you couldn't use type hinting to fix this?

Comment: In fact, OP used typehinting with `valueattr=...`. The problem is that empty string is evaluated to _falsey_, and everything get ruined.